# Has the Email service been Shutdown

Tags: support, email

Has the stackmail email service been shut down as I can't get access.

If it has can I get a forwarding message set up?

Comment: Yes, it has been shut down ... ten years ago, it looks like. I have a hard time imagining anybody is using it anymore ...